# Pegar o caminho dos arquivos de um commit com LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Como obter o caminho dos arquivos do meu último *commit*? Tenho esse método de exemplo:

```
private static void RepoListFiles()
{
    if (!arguments.ContainsKey("repository"))
    {
        Error("O repositório ainda não foi informado.");
        return;
    }

    using (repo)
    {
        if (repo.Head.Commits.Count() < 1)
        {
            Error("Nenhum Commit existente.");
            return;
        }

        Commit commit = repo.Commits.First();

        Tree tree = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commit.Sha).Tree;

        Console.WriteLine("\nSha: " + commit.Sha);
        if (commit.Author.Name != "Unknow") Console.WriteLine("Autor: " + commit.Author.Name);
        if (commit.Committer.Name != "Unknow") Console.WriteLine("Commiter: " + commit.Committer.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Data: " + commit.Author.When); //Commit-Date
        Console.WriteLine("Mensagem: " + commit.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        arquivos = new List<string>();
        GetFiles(tree);
        /*foreach (TreeEntry treeEntry in tree)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path: "   + treeEntry.Path);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: "   + treeEntry.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("---------");
        }*/

        foreach (string file in arquivos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");

    }
}

static void CompareTrees()
{
    using (repo)
    {
        Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
        Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree;

        var changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);

        TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChanges = changes.Single(c => c.Path == "1.txt");

        var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);
    }
}
```

Programa:

[image: Execução do programa]

Porém a saída não me trás o caminho todo.

Estructura do diretório

```
c:/teste
| - octocat.txt
| - parentoctocat.txt
| - /outros
| | - octocatblue.txt
| | - octored.txt
```

No meu *commit* possui apenas os arquivos `c:/teste/outros/octored.txt` e `c:/teste/outros/octocatblue.txt` adicionado.

Mas na saída vem todos os arquivos.

Como fazer para que venha apenas os arquivos adicionados no meu *commit*:

```
/outros/octocatblue.txt
/outros/octored.txt
```

---

<sub>**[Editado]** 

Obs.: Já consegui pegar o caminho completo do arquivo. Porém preciso apenas dos arquivos que eu adicionei no *commit* como `$ git add outros/octocatblue.txt`.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do Cigano responde a minha pergunta, porém ela ficou muito confusa pra mim e tive que pesquisar bastante para poder entende-la, levando em consideração que ainda estou aprendendo [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) e a biblioteca [gitlib2sharp](/questions/tagged/gitlib2sharp). Por isso estou postando a solução nua e crua.

---

Criei um método que compara as árvores pegando o *Commit* principal:

```
Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
```

E um outro *Commit*:

```
Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree;
```

E comparando a diferença:

```
var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);
```

Percorrendo essa diferênça `foreach (var ptc in patch)` eu consigo o caminho `ptc.Path` e o status `ptc.Status` (Added, Renamed, Deleted, Modified, etc...).

Método:

```
static void CompareTrees()
{
    using (repo)
    {
        Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree; // Arvore principal
        Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree; // Arvore anerior

        var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parentCommitTree, commitTree); // Diferênça

        foreach (var ptc in patch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ptc.Status +" -> "+ptc.Path); // Status -> Caminho do arquivo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que marcou a minha resposta como aceita? A sua resposta é melhor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez respondi depois que já tinha aceito e tem um tempo mínimo para que possa aceita-la

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente é comparando a árvore do commit anterior com a atual. [Aqui encontrei uma fixture utilizada no projeto para testar duas árvores que pode ajudar](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs#L46-77):

```
    public void CanCompareACommitTreeAgainstItsParent()
    {
        var path = SandboxStandardTestRepoGitDir();
        using (var repo = new Repository(path))
        {
            Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
            Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree;

            var changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);

            Assert.Equal(1, changes.Count());
            Assert.Equal(1, changes.Added.Count());

            TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChanges = changes.Single(c => c.Path == "1.txt");

            var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);
            Assert.False(patch["1.txt"].IsBinaryComparison);

            Assert.Equal("1.txt", treeEntryChanges.Path);
            Assert.Equal(ChangeKind.Added, treeEntryChanges.Status);

            Assert.Equal(treeEntryChanges, changes.Added.Single());

            Assert.Equal(Mode.Nonexistent, treeEntryChanges.OldMode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Então cara, eu não manjo muito de C#, esse "objeto" Assert não tem no meu projeto, deve ser algo do teste deles. Aquele `1.txt` é o arquivo que ele está comparando?

Comment: Eu atualizei meu código e o print ali na pergunta. Não consegui testar esse "exemplo" porque não o entendi, não sei se esse `1.txt` é o arquivo que está sendo comparado, ou se é o arquivo de onde armazena o resultado.

Comment: @KaduAmaral `Assert` é um conjunto de conjuntos para comparação. É usado para escrever testes unitários. `1.txt` é um arquivo qualquer que ele versionou e está verificando por mudanças.